# XSLT element in HTML element leads to errors

Tags: html, xslt, xhtml

how can i realize something like this:

```
<img alt="logo" src="/Content/Images/Logos/<xsl:value-of select="/customer/country"/>.png" />
```

The XSLT processor throws an error because of the "<" - sign here...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use:

```
<img alt="logo" >
     <xsl:attribute name="src">
        /Content/Images/Logos/<xsl:value-of select="/customer/country"/>.png
     </xsl:attribute>
</img>
```

Answer (score 0):

Elements cannot be nested within attribute values. You can use {...} to embed XPath as follows:

```
<img alt="logo" src="/Content/Images/Logos/{/customer/country}.png" />
```